# Crystal Reports 8.5 network file save

Tags: windows, crystal-reports, save

I have a user who suddenly started getting the following error:-
“File Save Failed
The document could not be saved in J:\XXXX\reports\xxxx.rpt.  It has been saved in C:\DOCUME~1\username\LOCALS~1\Temp\crw25.tmp.”

This started after the SQL server they use had an IP address update and when the laptop did an XP autoupdate.
The updates were removed, but this did not help and the SQL server was accessed with qulified name.

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ODBC try testing the connection there (Might have to rebuild). Flush DNS, try your normal network troubleshooting tools to verify connectivity. Also make sure the Mapped drive is connecting appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment, I will get the DNS flushed.

Just to add:-
If the user opens an exisiting report from the nertowrk drive then save it back it fails and deletes the file from the network.
I also have another user with this issue.
Keivn